# MS Access Macro to perform an update query and move file from one folder to another

Tags: ms-access, ms-access-2010

I have the code below which appends to the table labeled "Checks" in my database, however, it moves the file to "Documents" and I want it to move to the folder "C:\Users\User1\Desktop\TEst\Completed"

```
Sub Import_Multi_Excel_Files()

Dim InputFile As String  
Dim InputPath As String

InputPath = "C:\Users\User1\Desktop\TEst\Work\"  
InputFile = Dir(InputPath & "*.xls")

Do While InputFile <> ""  
    If InputFile Like "zz*" Then  
    Else  
        DoCmd.TransferSpreadsheet acImport, , "Checks", InputPath & InputFile,   True '< The true is for column headers  
        Name InputPath & InputFile As "Completed" & InputFile  
    End If  
    InputFile = Dir  
Loop  

End Sub
```

Comment: What is your specific problem, and what have you tried? Please read [ask] and [help/on-topic].

Comment: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff844793.aspx https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/gg251462.aspx

Comment: My issue is the output is routed to my "documents" folder instead of "C:\Users\User1\Desktop\TEst\Completed", where I would like it to be.  I added the code in my question and i am not sure how to change it, so the output is "C:\Users\User1\Desktop\TEst\Completed".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was able to solve this by changing

```
Name InputPath & InputFile As "Completed" & InputFile
```

to

```
Name InputPath & InputFile As InputPath & "Completed" & InputFile
```

I had to add InputPath after as.  This now saves the file in the same folder, but with completed in its name, so that it can't be imported a second time.